# Solr faceting on multivalued field with grouping

Tags: solr, full-text-search

I have schema, which looks something like this.

```
   <fields >
     <field name=“objectID” type=“string” docValues=“true” required=“true”/>
     <field name=“skuID” type=“string” indexed=“true” required=“true” />
     <field name=“category” type=“int” multiValued=“true” indexed=“true” docValues=“true”/>
     <field name=“disc” type=“float” />
   </fields>
   <uniqueKey>objectID</uniqueKey>
   <solrQueryParser defaltOperator=“OR” />
```

I want to group results on `skuID`  where i want distinct `skuID` count of each category.

I ran query like,

```
group=true&group.field=skuID&group.facet=true&facet=true&facet.field=category&group.ngroups=true&facet.mincount=1
```

or

```
{
group: true,
group.field: "skuID",
group.facet: true,
group.ngroups: true,
facet: true,
facet.fields: "category"
}
```

and it is showing me error.

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception during facet.field: category

unexpected docvalues type SORTED_NUMERIC for field 'category' (expected one of [SORTED, SORTED_SET])
```

Comment: Btw very there is new concept called collapsing (https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collapse-and-expand-results.html)  in solr.

I used this for my problem.